# CAST(message AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Exceptions.ParseException: '')' or ',' expected'

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

Any idea how can I fix this issue, what wrong in my where statement? The I need to cast the message field because in Database it has datatype of ntext. Thank you for the help!

Here is my code

```
IQueryable<DataDto> query = _dbContext.EntityQuery<Data>(
                    sort: pagingInfo.SortExpression,
                    filter: "(CAST(message AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) = \"No Records Were Found\")",
                ).ProjectTo<DataDto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider);
```

EntityQuery

```
public virtual IQueryable<T> EntityQuery<T>(bool trackChanges = true, string filter = null, string sort = null, int? quantity = null, int? offset = null, string include = null) where T : class, new()
        {
            return this.Set<T>().WithTracking(trackChanges).With(include).Filter(filter).Sort(sort).Top(quantity, offset);
        }
```

Filter Extension

```
public static IQueryable<T> Filter<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string filterExpression)
        {
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filterExpression) ? query.Where(filterExpression) : query;
        }
```

Comment: The library you are using has its own query language, but still against C# objects/properties (similar to LIQ, but with strings). The important is that it is **not** SQL.